# Read from a manually writen .txt file. Windows Phone 8 Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I created a .txt file with data to load into a LongListSelector, but I cannot figure out how can I read the data from it. Using StreamReader with exact file path, the app crashes and with IsolatedStorage, it doesn't seen the .txt file.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your .txt file located, is it in the Isolated Storage?

If it's not, your Silverlight application [will need to be "Trusted"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721082%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (more on [trusted applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721083%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)).

If it is in the Isolated Storage, then you should not have any issue reading it using something like this.

```
var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
try
{
    if (store.FileExists(path))
    {
        using (var stream = store.OpenFile("fileName", FileMode.Open))
        {
            //Read your file
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //Handle Exception
}
```

Keep in mind that Isolated Storages are separate for each application. If your file has been created by another application in its Isolated Storage, you won't be able to access it.

Comment: I knew about IsolatedStorage and it seems that I will use it... Thanks!